# How can I have two Netflix profiles set up under one account?

Tags: netflix

My girlfriend and I don't necessarily like all of the same movies so I was wondering if there is a way to have two profiles set up for one account. We live together and are currently trying Netflix streaming (no DVDs). Is there a way to keep our movie ratings separate somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Now days (from 2013 actually) there are profiles in Netflix.

Quoting:

> [How do profiles work on my Netflix account?](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/10421)
>
> **Profiles allow different members of your household to have their own personalized Netflix experience**, built around the TV shows and movies they enjoy. You can have up to five individual profiles within a single Netflix account.
>
> <sub>Note: Profiles are not available on devices produced before 2013.</sub>
>
> Each profile allows for its own:
>
> - Personalized TV show and movie suggestions
> - Recently Watched list
> - Ratings and Reviews
> - Language preference
> - Playback settings
> - Maturity level
> - My List